# Writing an MPS I get "OS Error: SCIP: cannot create file!"

Tags: scip, pyscipopt

I was trying to write an MPS using pyscipopt.writeProblem() but I am getting this error, which I had never gotten before and there does not seem to be any information available other than what its message says.

Is there any problem with authentication? Is SCIP or PyScipOpt not installed correctly?

I first ran it as an administrator, and I also tried reinstalling PyScipOpt. However, I still get the same OSError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSError you are seeing when trying to write a MPS file using pyscipopt.writeProblem() could be caused by a variety of issues. Some possible causes could include:

Incorrect file path: Make sure that you are specifying a valid file path for the MPS file you are trying to create. The path should be a string that points to the location where you want to save the file, and it should include the file name and the .mps file extension.

Insufficient permissions: If you are trying to save the MPS file to a location that requires special permissions, such as a system folder or a protected network location, you may need to run the script as an administrator or with the appropriate permissions to access the location.

Installation issues: If you are using PyScipOpt to create the MPS file, make sure that it is installed correctly and that all of its dependencies are installed and up to date. You may also want to try reinstalling PyScipOpt to see if that resolves the issue.

Other system issues: The OSError could also be caused by other system-level issues, such as a problem with your operating system or a problem with the file system. In this case, you may need to troubleshoot the issue further or seek assistance from a technical support person.

I hope this information helps!